# Closed Linestring

Tags: postgis, linestring

I've created a linestring using st_makeline(). When I draw this linestring using QGIS it always makes it closed. The start and end points are not the same and I verified by using st_startpoint() and st_endpoint(). To be double sure I also ran st_isclosed() on the linestring and it returned false.

Here is a SC of the points that are part of the linestring. You can clearly see it starting and ending in the top left.

[image]

Now when I use the st_makeline() function I get the following result where it closes the trajectory. Is my data incorrect or am I missing something in QGIS when I'm drawing the layer?

[image]

Link for WKT file of trajectory: [WKT-for-linestring.txt](https://drive.google.com/a/przemeklach.com/file/d/0BxjEOA-a6hiLUVl6eTJZZDNQbW8/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: can you add some info re. what data source this is coming from, ie. PostGIS, etc.?

Comment: Ya it's coming from PostGIS. The original data was in a text file which I then imported into PostGIS via ST_MakePoint() and then used those points to create my linestring via ST_MakeLine(). The points are stored as WGS84 4326.

Comment: Copy-paste the WKT that you get by pushing your geometry from MakeLine through ST_AsText so we can check it.

Comment: @user30184 I've added a link to the file in the original question. There are lots of points so pasting in comments section would not have worked.

Comment: Hm I just realized that my altitude is out to lunch. I'm going to fix that. Although, that shouldn't affect the way the line is closed?

Comment: With that WKT the linestring is closed from the west so QGIS does not have any role in this play. But that WKT is just one simple linestring - you can't draw your roads as you want with a pen without lifting it or returning the same path. What you want is probably a multilinestring or a bunch of simple lines, one per road.

Comment: @user30184 So what you're saying is that I can't do something like st_makeline(points) where points is a list of points, in the correct order, that I want to use to draw a line?

Comment: Without a controlled test I can't say but first thing I would check is if you really feed vertices into MakeLine in the order that you believe. The first point of your line is 116.3196983 39.9848666. What you say is that your SQL did not feed that as a start point into MakeLine but PostGIS has decided to order vertices into some other order. If you can prove that it feels like a bug in PostGIS.

Answer (score 1):

You were wrong with the start and end points. First and last vertices of the WKT are not at top left but they are closer to bottom right as marked in this image. First and last vertices do not have same coordinates and therefore the linestring is not closed even it looks like it was. Vertices are about 0.000113 degrees apart.

[image]